# The table aliases does not return results

Tags: sql, column-alias

I'm working on a practice problem and trying to use the table alias in the ON field but it's not working.

```
SELECT c.code AS country_code, name, year, inflation_rate
FROM countries AS c
Join to economies (alias e)
  INNER JOIN economies AS e
    **ON c.code = e.code;**
```

here's the standard answer

```
SELECT c.code AS country_code, name, year, inflation_rate
FROM countries AS c
Join to economies (alias e)
  INNER JOIN economies AS e
    **ON countries_code = e.code;**
```

This is what I entered

The standard answer wants me to use "c.code" in the ON field but I tried to use the alias "country_code" instead, and it wouldn't return any results.

Comment: You cannot use column aliases in `ON` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` cannot be used in the `FROM` (and hence not in subsidiary clauses such as `ON`) or `WHERE` clauses.

Some databases allow aliases in the `GROUP BY` and/or `HAVING` clauses.  All (or almost all) allow them in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Where aliases are available is referred to as *scoping*.